# How to add a CSS transition while keeping previously declared transitions

Tags: css, syntax, css-transitions

Say we got an element which has a transition. How can one add a class with a transition for another transition property without overwriting and so disabling the other transition?

**Example**

HTML:

```
<div class="foo bar">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet …
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bar {
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  /* This of course overwrites .foo */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't. You would have to write a new selector .foo.bar with both transitions stated. –

```
.foo {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bar {
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}

.foo.bar {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: I thought so. It would be a useful feature for a future version of CSS, as it would keep the code more modular. In a more complex scenario, `.foo` and  `.bar` could be two completely seperate modules, but at the moment they have to be mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

Like you would do with any other CSS property, **redeclare**.

```
.foo {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bar {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: The point is I do not want to redeclare but to add a transition as the specification allows multiple instances in the `transition` shorthand

Comment: @luke See SCSS or LESS.